What is SRCfile() function in ILE C++ Compiler?
ILE C++ is a compiler produced by IBM , This compiler has a function called SRCfile.
SRCfile()  is defined as follows by IBM :
“The name of the file that you reference on the #include directive in the source program.
The output file is generated in the Data Management file system.“
Can you explain more about , What is SRCfile function and how it is related to “the Data Management file system” please?
